# What's wrong with my solution for equation $x^{1/2} + 3x^{-1/2} -10x^{-3/2}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The solution given in the website:

[image: The Solution Given in the website]

Here's my solution:

[image: My solution]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing.  But the solution $x=-5$ has to be rejected as (assuming you want real solutions) $\sqrt {-5}$ does not exist.  You'll note that the "book" solution also comes up with (and rejects) the solution associated with $-5$.

Comment: Your solution $x=0$ is spurious. When $x=0$, you have $1+\frac{3}{x}-\frac{10}{x^2}=\infty$. Otherwise your solution is correct.

Comment: This is neat but next time you should type out all your steps using Mathjax at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: @lulu I agree that $(-5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is not real, but nonetheless $-5$ is a real solution to the original equation (which I note uses $x^\frac{1}{2}$ rather than $\sqrt{x}$).

Comment: You have to go back and then discard your $x=-5$

Comment: But $-5$ is not in the domain of $x^{\frac 12}$, so it is not a valid solution.  Similarly, $x=0$ must be rejected as it is not in the domain of $x^{-\frac 12}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct, but you aren't quite finished. If you attempted to plug $-5$ back into the original equation, you would have:

$(-5)^{\frac{1}{2}}+3(-5)^{-\frac{1}{2}}=10(-5)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

But those exponents involving halves are really square roots, and is $-5$ in the domain of the square root function? No. Thus that solution is extraneous.

Comment: Maybe -5 is not in the domain of $\sqrt{x}$, but it is in the domain of $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ surely?

Comment: @almagest, this is very likely for a precalculus or college algebra class so I highly doubt they're making that distinction here.

Comment: $\sqrt{-5}=(-5)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ If $-5$ is not in the domain of $\sqrt{x}$ then we should not expect it to be in the domain of $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ (unless you want your codomain to be $\mathbb{C}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$....

Comment: @tilper Possibly, but it is an unfortunate question since it is easy to verify that $-5$ is a solution to the original equation (provided you are happy to stray into complex numbers in your verification).

Comment: The standard assumption through first year calculus, with the rare exception, is that functions have codomain$=\mathbb{R}$ unless otherwise stated.

Comment: @almagest This depends on the context. This is the case in the computer algebra system. However there many sites that state $x^{1/2}$ is a function with a positive domain.

Comment: @JustinBenfield Note also that his solution gave $x=0$ as a solution.

Comment: @almagest He also didn't mention that in his final solution set, so I think he realized that it was not in the domain of the original equation (because of division by $0$ problem). In either case, you are correct that $x=0$ is not a solution because of the division by $0$ problem.